# Image overlay transition - handling pinterest button and caption elements

Tags: html, css, pinterest

I've been wrangling with how to handle a hover event for a block element containing an image, a caption placed on top of the image via absolute positioning, and a pinterest pin it button which should display on hover (anywhere in the block element).

The issue is how best to handle the overlay transition when the element is hovered over, without the transition hiding the pinterest button. As can be seen from my snippet, I'm trying to apply a darkened background with opacity to the image on hover (but leaving the caption content clear to read). Unfortunately my code in the snippet results in the background applied on hover hiding the pinterest button.

I also want the pinterest pin it button to appear when the caption is hovered over - currently, if you remove the background transition from my snippet, you can see that the pinterest button appears only when hovering on the image directly - as the caption sits on top of the image in the stack, when you hover over the caption the pinterest button is hidden.

The html structure is simple and as below:

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="#">
<div class="featured-image">
  <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7027/6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg">
</div>
<div class="caption">
  <h4>Blurb</h4>
  <span class="button">Read More</span>
</div>
  </a>
</div>
<script async defer data-pin-hover="true"  src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yrssssk0/

Comment: Try adding `pointer-events: none` on the `:after` overlay.

Comment: Added that to the overlay _and_ the caption div and that worked a treat. Do you want to add as an answer that I can accept?